# Handle enter on ftxui menu example

Tags: menu, console-application

I'm trying to modify the ftxui library example where there is an interactive menu. I would like to handle the enter key so that the selection is made with this enter and I can move on to other screens. The example captures the selection well, but I'm not able to capture the enter. I'm not very knowledgeable about this tool so I'm trying to modify their example as little as possible.

The example is from this link:
[examples/component/menu_entries_animated.cpp](https://arthursonzogni.github.io/FTXUI/examples_2component_2menu_entries_animated_8cpp-example.html)

Below is my modified version, using the 'x' key for simplicity:

```
auto renderer = Renderer(menu, [&] {
        if (menu->OnEvent(ftxui::Event::Character('x')))
        {
            std::cout << "x\n";
        }
        return vbox({
                   hbox(text("selected = "), text(std::to_string(selected))),
                   separator(),
                   menu->Render() | frame,
            }) |
            border | bgcolor(Color::Black);
        });
```

From my understanding it should work, but it's not working. Could someone please give me a light on what I'm missing?

OBS: The example works fine, I just can't handle the key pressing event.

Answer (score 1):

After a few tries and study and I thank Lucas for the help, I was able to see how it does.

We should after the menu declaration add a handler to the event:

```
m_menu = Container::Vertical(
    m_json_menu_entries,
    &m_selected);

m_menu |= CatchEvent([&](Event event) {
    bool ret = (ftxui::Event::Character('\n') == event);
    return ret;
    });
```

This should be called once, and the event will be handled by the lambda every time.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you should use

`Event::Special(Event::Return))`

But I'm not familiar with the lib

Reference:
https://arthursonzogni.github.io/FTXUI/event_8cpp_source.html

Comment: This particular suggestion didn't work but it helped me see which way I should take to find the solution, thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Montes' answer is exactly right, but it wasn't immediately clear to me how to apply it, so I'll add an additional example. ChatGPT/CoPilot were very insistent on variations of the following WRONG syntax. It had no idea how to apply `Event` or `OnEvent()` and difficulty writing the correct `main(){}` for a FTXUI demo.

```
// Don't Do this:
Component App(bool& is_right_column_collapsed) {
  return Renderer([&] { return App(is_right_column_collapsed); })
    .OnEvent(& {           // <-- Wrong 
      if (event == Event::Custom) {
        is_right_column_collapsed = !is_right_column_collapsed;
      }
    });
}
```

The correct answer is to use `CatchEvent()`. The key to understanding Montes' answer was reading in the FTXUI docs:

> "CatchEvent() - Return a component, using |on_event| to catch events.
> This function *must* returns true when the event has been handled,
> false otherwise."
> https://arthursonzogni.github.io/FTXUI/namespaceftxui.html#ad2948235799c010c76c6de861c050c59

where we see the correct `CatchEvent()` example:

```
auto screen = ScreenInteractive::TerminalOutput();
auto renderer = Renderer([] { return text("Hello world"); });
renderer |= CatchEvent([&](Event event) {
  if (event == Event::Character('q')) {
    screen.ExitLoopClosure()();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});
screen.Loop(renderer);
```

The next paragraph describes `Maybe()` to "maybe display", a component which I also needed.

To show `CatchEvent()` in a different context and demonstrate how the pieces come together, my solution looked like this. My goal was to create three framed columns, where the back-tick key ( ` ) displays/hides the right column. Notice the use of `Maybe()` to "maybe display" a component. There are two events

- back-tick ` - displays/hides right column
- 'q' key - quits program

```cpp
    Element LeftColumn() {
        return vbox({
            text(L"Left Column"),
        }) | border  | size(WIDTH, LESS_THAN, 60);
    }
    
    Element MiddleColumn() { ... }
    Element RightColumn() { ... }
    
    Component App(bool& is_right_column_collapsed) {
        // Create a component that can be turned on/off with 'Maybe()'
        auto rightColumnComponent = Renderer([&] { return RightColumn(); });
        auto maybeShown = Maybe(rightColumnComponent, &is_right_column_collapsed);

        // Define the main-layout Component
        auto myapp = Container::Horizontal({
            Renderer([&] { return LeftColumn(); }),
            Renderer([&] { return MiddleColumn(); }),
            maybeShown,
          });
    
        // Decorate main Component with events.
        myapp = myapp | CatchEvent( [&] (Event event) {
              if (event == Event::Character('`')) {
                  is_right_column_collapsed = !is_right_column_collapsed;
                  return true;               // CatchEvent() MUST return true if event was handled,
              }
              return false;                  // or false if it wasn't!
          } );
    
        return myapp;
    }
    
    
    int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
        bool is_right_column_collapsed = false;
    
        auto app = App(is_right_column_collapsed);
        auto screen = ScreenInteractive::FitComponent();
        
        // Decorate app component with 'quit' event.
        app |=  CatchEvent( [&](Event event) {
            if (event == Event::Character('q')) {
                screen.ExitLoopClosure()();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    
        screen.Loop(app);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you're new to FTXUI it uses a lot of lambdas. If your uncomfortable with lambdas, I found this talk helpful in working with this library. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jCOwajNch0